# How to test service files using wct in polymer if it doesn't contain any custom component

Tags: polymer, polymer-1.0, polymer-3.x, web-component-tester, wct

I would like to write unit test case for a service file named session.js, 
   where there is no custom element is defined. Can we call functions 
   defined in service file from Polymer WCT.

```
export const ValidateSession=()=>{  
       try{   
           return (logindate <= session);   
       }
       catch(e){   
           console.log(e.message);   
       }   
   }
```

In my service file, function is defined like above. How to write unit test case to check above function is being called or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do everything you would do to [test an element](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/tools/tests), but without an element fixture, or perhaps using a JS-only test suite:

```js
suite('AwesomeLib', function() {
  test('is awesome', function() {
    assert.isTrue(AwesomeLib.awesome);
  });
});
```

Such test suites are described in the [WCT README](https://github.com/Polymer/tools/tree/master/packages/web-component-tester).